# Capture interactive Python shell output along with input

Tags: python, bash, shell, stdout, stdin

I want to capture the Python shell output along with the input sent to it. For example, in the following use case, help() should also be present in Line 4 of capture.log:

```
$ echo "help()" | python3 -i > capture.log   2>&1
$ cat capture.log
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
Welcome to Python 3.4's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/.
....
....
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a Unix-like environment, you can capture all `tty` input and output with the `script` command:

```
$ script capture.log
Script started, output file is capture.log
$ python3
# python interactive session here
$ exit
Script done, output file is capture.log
$ cat capture.log
Script started on Thu Aug 18 21:21:55 2016
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 21 2016, 07:25:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help()

Welcome to Python 3.5's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at http://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/.

....
....
>>> ^D
$ exit

Script done on Thu Aug 18 21:22:06 2016
```

If, as in the question example, Python is driven completely by `stdin` pipe and the goal is to capture the pipe input and Python output, you can get close by using the `tee` command:

```
$ echo "help()" | tee capture.log | python3 -i >> capture.log 2>&1
$ cat capture.log 
help()
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 21 2016, 07:25:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
Welcome to Python 3.5's help utility!

If this is your first time using Python, you should definitely check out
the tutorial on the Internet at http://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/.
....
....
```

As you can see, the input and output are both captured, but they're not aligned.